# Slim Framework One route different methods

Tags: php, rest, get, routes, slim

I am trying to build a simple REST API for a dictionary App. I would like to have two `GET` methods that will get you the word by id and query(string). The problem is that the Slim framework routes everything through the first method and ignores the second one. I understand why it does it and I know you can use query string params but I am hoping there would be a way I can accomplish it this way. Thank you for your help.

```
http://localhost:5000/dictionary_api/words/1
$app->get('/words/:id', function($id) use ($app, $db) {
});


http://localhost:5000/dictionary_api/words/hello
$app->get('/words/:word', function($word) use ($app,$db){
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can supply an array of conditions (regex matches) so that the route parameter will only match a certain format. Try the following

```
$app->get('/words/:id', function($id) use ($app, $db)
{
    //
})->conditions(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
```

This will make the `:id` parameter only match numeric values, anything else it shouldn't match and skip onto the next route.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. Worked perfectly.